# How to find High Price for a Stock using custom time period, using Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Given `stock symbol` and `time period in days` I would like to know what the High/ Min price was?

Today I `=IFERROR(GOOGLEFINANCE("QQQ", "price", (today() - AB19), today(), "DAILY"))` and then check `=max(AB21:AB203)` and it works.

The problem here is `AB19`. Each time I make a change to time period it makes a call to Google and Google doesn't like being called too many times.

I would like to make 1 call, say with `AB19` bring equal to `365` and then query same dataset for `MAX` in say `43` days.

How can this be done please?

**EDIT**: I was trying to use filter function, `=filter(AB21:AB271,AA21:AA271 >10/1/2021)`, but there is an issue somewhere

[image]

Comment: it doesn't make sense to make calls for prices in the past. Just keep the last year of prices for your tickers as "hard data".  Then you add a row every day with the live price that gets converted into "hard data" at the end of the day.  That's how most people do it in Google Sheets.  Then finding the max or min in a year is a simple MAX() or MIN() or MAXIFS() or MINIFS() formula.

Comment: @mattking, yes, this is valid! Thank you.